# PrintWriter sends and DataInputStream reads it

Tags: java, io

I got server-client application. On the client side, I am using this I/O stream to output data:

```
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("yeah");
```

On the server side I am trying to read the product by this line:

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    String clientId = din.readUTF();
```

The server reaches the above statement and stops there. What's the problem? Are the two I/O streams not compatible with each other?
There are no exceptions thrown by either party, no output. I simply added `System.out.println()` before and after the above statement I=and I determined that the program does not cross this line:`String clientId = din.readUTF();`

Comment: what does "The server reaches the above statement and stops there" mean, do you get an exception, error, what? Give details on the problem so that people can understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` method if you want to read from the other end of the socket with `DataInputStream.readUTF()`. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) on `DataInput` for more detail on why. As an alternative, try using a [buffered reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) or scanner to read in your data.